# Hiding the overflow from an absolutely positioned descendant in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have an absolutely positioned element that's a child of an element with `overflow:hidden`, and I'd like to have it be cut off at the edge of the parent, but absolute positioned elements seem to ignore overflow rules. Is there a workaround for this?

http://www.brandonsmith.ninja

Viewed on mobile, the tessellation elements are what I'm trying to cut off. The document currently expands beyond the viewport width.

Comment: set any position to the container other than the default `static` and it will work

Comment: That depends. Do you want the absposed element to be relative to that element? If so, position: relative will ensure it respects the overflow: hidden - and it should be there to begin with. Seeing as the absposed element doesn't have any offsets, adding position: relative shouldn't interfere with anything else other than the clipping of the absposed element.

Comment: Oriol, do you have a link to the question this seems to be a duplicate of?

Answer (score 2):

Use `position: relative;` on second container. This will solve the issue.[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uftm8L8q/3/)

```
<div class="container abs">
  <div class="child two">
    absolute positioning
  </div>
</div>
```

For your mobile problem: add `overflow-x: hidden;` to `<body>` css rules.

```
.abs{
   position:relative;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Hmm... It seems I didn't faithfully reproduce my real use case, because that solution doesn't work for it. I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: where is the issue in the website?

Comment: The red and orange triangles, but only when viewed on a mobile viewport small enough for them to go off the edge. The document grows to fit them, beyond the width of the viewport.

Comment: Solved: see updated answer